# Selecting a compiler for a make file

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction

Say you have both VS2008 and VS 6 installed on your computer,
and you wish to write an make file that will compile some C++ code using
the VS 6.0 compiler. How can you do that? What is the way to control the selection
of the compiler outside the make file?

Thanks

Comment: If you have VS installed, why do you need a make file?

Comment: This is irrelevant to the question. We're dealing with an enormous product, partially C++ and partially .NET, written patches on patches, and the only way to compile it properly is using an external instructions script (the make file). What I specifically need here is to compile only using VS6. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that VS 6.0 had VCVARS32.BAT but if there is VCVARS32.BAT then you need to set your environment using VCVARS32.BAT. See [Building from the Command Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd%28v=VS.71%29.aspx), "Running VCVARS32.BAT".

If you need VS 2008 than you run VCVARS32.BAT from VS 2008. 
If you need VS 6.0 than you run VCVARS32.BAT from VS 6.0.

Again, I am not sure that VS 6.0 had VCVARS32.BAT so check it.

For example building Hello, World program might look like:

```
"D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat" && cl hello_world.cpp
```